# Having Issues Inflating Layout for Custom Recycler View

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am getting a force close with the following exceptions when I try to bind to a recycler view with my custom adapter. I am really losing my mind with this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
try {
        games = new Game(this).getInCompleteGames();

        GameListAdapter gameAdapter = new GameListAdapter(this, games);

        rv.setAdapter(gameAdapter);
        rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        custFuncs.MsgBox(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Error Log**

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class layout
>                                                                                            Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class layout
>                                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.layout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.slistersoft.slistersoftspadesscorepad-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.slistersoft.slistersoftspadesscorepad-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.slistersoft.slistersoftspadesscorepad-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.slistersoft.slistersoftspadesscorepad-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.slistersoft.slistersoftspadesscorepad-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.slistersoft.slistersoftspadesscorepad-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.slistersoft.slistersoftspadesscorepad-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.slistersoft.slistersoftspadesscorepad-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.slistersoft.slistersoftspadesscorepad-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.slistersoft.slistersoftspadesscorepad-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.slistersoft.slistersoftspadesscorepad-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.slistersoft.slistersoftspadesscorepad-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.slistersoft.slistersoftspadesscorepad-2/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
>                                                                                                at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>                                                                                                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
>                                                                                                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
>                                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:609)
>                                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:700)
>                                                                                                at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:68)
>                                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:717)
>                                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:785)
>                                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
>                                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
>                                                                                                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
>                                                                                                at com.slistersoft.slistersoftspadesscorepad.GameListAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(GameListAdapter.java:64)
>                                                                                                at com.slistersoft.slistersoftspadesscorepad.GameListAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(GameListAdapter.java:16)
>                                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6367)
>                                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5555)
>                                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5440)
>                                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5436)
>                                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2224)
>                                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1551)
>                                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1511)
>                                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:595)
>                                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3583)
>                                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3312)
>                                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3844)
>                                                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
>                                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
>                                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
>                                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
>                                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
>                                                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
>                                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
>   10-01 23:19:02.745 9478-9478/com.slistersoft.slistersoftspadesscorepad E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>                                                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>                                                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
>                                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
>                                                                                                at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:437)
>                                                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
>                                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
>                                                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>                                                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>                                                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
>                                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
>                                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
>                                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
>                                                                                                at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
>                                                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
>                                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
>                                                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>                                                                                                at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>                                                                                                at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:726)
>                                                                                                at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
>                                                                                                at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
>                                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2346)
>                                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2068)
>                                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
>                                                                                                at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6337)
>                                                                                                at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:874)
>                                                                                                at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
>                                                                                                at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:621)
>                                                                                                at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)
>                                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

**GameListAdapter Class**

```
package com.slistersoft.slistersoftspadesscorepad;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GameListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GameListAdapter.GameViewHolder> {

private List<Game> mGames;
private Context callingContext;
private CUSTOM_FUNCTIONS custFuncs;

public class GameViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView tvT1Name, tvT2Name, tvT1Score, tvT2Score, tvDateStarted;

    public GameViewHolder(View itemView){

        super(itemView);

        // Stores the itemView in a public final member variable that can be used
        // to access the context from any ViewHolder instance.

        //region Initialize Game Card Controls

        tvT1Name = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.rv_tvTeam1Name);
        tvT2Name = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.rv_tvTeam2Name);
        tvT1Score = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.rv_tvT1ScoreDisplay);
        tvT2Score = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.rv_tvT2ScoreDisplay);
        tvDateStarted = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.rv_tvDateStartedLabel);


        //endregion

    }




}

public GameListAdapter(Context callingContext, ArrayList<Game> gamesList) {
    this.mGames = gamesList;
    this.callingContext = callingContext;
    custFuncs = new CUSTOM_FUNCTIONS(callingContext);
}

@Override
public GameListAdapter.GameViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    Context context = parent.getContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    //Inflate Custom Game Card Layout
    View gameView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_game_row_layout, parent, false);

    //Return a new holder instance

    GameViewHolder vh = new GameViewHolder(gameView);

    return vh;

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(GameListAdapter.GameViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

    try {
        //Get the data model based on position
        Game game = mGames.get(position);

        //Set layout controls based on game object

        //Set text on controls
        viewHolder.tvT1Name.setText(game.getTeam1Name());
        viewHolder.tvT2Name.setText(game.getTeam2Name());
        viewHolder.tvT1Score.setText(game.getTeam1Score());
        viewHolder.tvT2Score.setText(game.getTeam2Score());
        viewHolder.tvDateStarted.setText(game.getHumanDateStartedString());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        custFuncs.MsgBox(e.getMessage());
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mGames.size();
}

public Context getContext() {
    return callingContext;
}

}
```

**recyclerview_game_row_layout.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="12dp"
    app:cardElevation="12dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rv_gameCardLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/staticGameCardLabel"
            android:textSize="@dimen/rv_cardHeader1FontSize"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rv_tvTeam1Name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/t1NamePlaceholder"
            android:textSize="@dimen/rv_cardHeader2FontSize"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/staticVersusLabel"
            android:textSize="@dimen/rv_cardHeader2FontSize"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rv_tvTeam2Name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/t2NamePlaceholder"
            android:textSize="@dimen/rv_cardHeader2FontSize"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/scoreLayout"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvStaticScoreDisplay"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/scoreLabel"
                android:textSize="@dimen/rv_cardHeader2FontSize"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rv_tvT1ScoreDisplay"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:text="@string/scorePlaceholder"
                android:textSize="@dimen/rv_cardHeader2FontSize"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rv_tvScoreSeperator"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:text="@string/scoreSeperator"
                android:textSize="@dimen/rv_cardHeader2FontSize"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rv_tvT2ScoreDisplay"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
                android:text="@string/scorePlaceholder"
                android:textSize="@dimen/rv_cardHeader2FontSize"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rv_tvDateStartedLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/startedDateLabel"
            android:textSize="@dimen/rv_cardHeader2FontSize"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**Layout XML Recycler View is in:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
tools:context="com.slistersoft.slistersoftspadesscorepad.GamePickerActivity"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/gamePickerRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: There's a problem in your xml file. post it.

Comment: Add your xml files.

Comment: My fault I should have posted the XML to begin with. I will post as soon as I get home. Thanks for the quick response though.

Comment: I've added the XML files to my original post.

Answer (score 3):

Data binding might not be enabled for your app, ensure that your app module's build.gradle contains:

```
android {
    ...
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
```

For further information, see the [Data Binding Library documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/start).

Comment: That fixed my issue, thank you. Interestingly, it was being triggered by using a `<layout>` element as the root for my layout file. That tag was new to me but I didn't know it was related to the data binding library, thought I could just copy it since it was cleaner than using a specific layout file. I guess it's time that I read about the databinding library.